# Advice on a dynamic jquery tree picker, populated from a restful json web service

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, dynamic, treeview

Suppose I have the following organization structure stored in a database:

> KingRobert id=1
>
> - Joffrey  id=4
> - Circe    id=2
>
>   - Minion1 id=77
>   - Minion2  id=80
> - Jaimey id=3
>
>   - Minion3

& a web service which returns the children of the selected person.   So

```
/WesterosOrgChart/Getsubordinates/KingRobert
```

returns

```
[
{"id":"4","name":"Joffrey"},
{"id":"2","name":"Circe"},
{"id":"3","name":"Jaimey"}
]
```

&

```
/WesterosOrgChart/Getsubordinates/Circe
```

returns

```
[
{"id":"77","name":"Minion1"},
{"id":"80","name":"Minion2"}
]
```

etc...
What is the best ( most stable, efficient, easiest to code...)  JQuery based tree picker to navigate & select from this that will :

1 let me select a name value at any node OR expand a node with children, so you can pick any name in the hierarchy.

2 Delay populating child nodes until the relevant parent is actually expanded ( aka lazy loading).  I do not want to load hundreds or thousands of rows, that will not be needed, when the page first opens.

Almost all the examples I have seen are static, with the entire hierarchy loaded when the page is opened.  I need an example that defaults to

/WesterosOrgChart/Getsubordinates/KingRobert

, but is subsequently capable of rerunning the service with a different parameter.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/), it accepts input from JSON